# Silverstripe install root folder public

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have installed silverstripe 4 into the /var/www/html folder in apache.
However, when I go to the url, I have to use "localhost/public/index.php" in order to obtain the main page. I thought I was to be able to just go to "localhost" to find the defaut page. What am I to do if I want to have a main page without people having to specify "/public/" before it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, your localhost website can be resolved without adding `/public/` if the following 2 things are configured correctly.

- Enable Apache mod_rewrite
- Having [.htaccess](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer/blob/4/.htaccess#L2) rewrite config in `/var/www/html`

**Troubleshooting**

1. Check if you got the right [.htaccess](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer/blob/4/.htaccess#L2) in `/var/www/html`. Basically, this Apache config file will forward all the requests to `/public/` folder.
2. If [.htaccess](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer/blob/4/.htaccess#L2) is fine, make sure your mod_rewrite is enabled in your Apache. Check this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-1-%E2%80%94-enabling-mod_rewrite).